# Connection Error when trying to talk with a VM through Docker api

Tags: python, api, sockets, docker

I greet the community! I was trying to connect to an ip using docker api (python library) when it produced this error:

```
     File "docker_launcher.py", line 12, in <module>
     response = [line for line in cli.build(fileobj = f, path='C:\Users\atrestis\ptest')]
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 97, in build
     timeout=timeout,
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 47, in inner
     return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 108, in _post
    return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 511, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 437, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.99.1', port=2376): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.21/build?q=False&pull=False&nocache=False&forcerm=False&rm=False (Caused by strong textNewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02BDEC70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

Here is my code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from docker import Client
dockerfile = '''
# Shared Volume

FROM python:2-onbuild
CMD ["python", "./demo.py" ]
'''
f = BytesIO(dockerfile.encode('utf-8'))
cli = Client(base_url='tcp://192.168.99.1:2376')
response = [line for line in cli.build(fileobj = f, path='C:\User\atrestis\ptest')]
```

It appears to be a problem with the TCP-IP. 
Any help would be much appreciated.